# VBA Macro to generate pdf (PC and Mac)

Tags: excel, vba, macos, pdf

I have a simple code that runs and allows me to preview a doc via pdf. It works great on a PC but when using a Mac machine I get a

> run time error: Error while printing.

[image]

Is there a way to alter the this code to accomodate both PC and Mac? (Version 2016/365)

Following code works for PC:

```
Sub ViewAsPDF()

    Worksheets("Quote (2)").ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:="Quote" & "_" & Worksheets("Quote (2)").Range("C8") & "_" & Format(Now, "MMDDYYYY_HHMM"), _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: I've added the information to the question. FWIW I tested, it ran once and saved the file. I did some "fiddling around" and after that got exactly the same as you. I did some research (google) and turned up others with the same problem. It appears to be an issue with the Mac. I hope the additional tags I added might get an answer from others with a better idea. You might find Ron de Bruins info helpful; starting with https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac020.htm Ron tends to hang out on the Microsoft Answers site.